# what is the difference between a normal reference and a read-only reference in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm confused about the differences between a normal ordinary reference to a read-only reference. The following two points are from [http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/~volkov/C++.pdf](http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/%7Evolkov/C++.pdf).

> A reference must be initialized when it is declared, and cannot be modified subsequently. In other words, you cannot use the reference to address a different variable at a later stage.
>
> A reference that addresses a constant object must be a constant itself, that is, it must be defined using the const keyword to avoid modifying the object by reference.

I was wondering, how to understand it? A normal reference is different to a read-only (or constant) reference; because a read-only reference can point to a constant object, in contrast to  a normal reference. But the above two points are really confusing...Especially, "a reference must be initialized when it is declared, and cannot be modified later".

EDIT: sorry that I did not make it clear earlier. What I intended to ask is that, what is the difference between a normal reference and a read-only reference? It has nothing to do with pointers for now.

EDIT again: I finally figure it out. For completeness, the following is the code and comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string line(50, '-');

    /* a constant reference, non-constant object */
    int i=42;                 // a non-constant object
    const int& r1 =i;        // a constant reference r1, which reference the earlier defined variable i
    //r1 = 6*9;                // Error: tried to change the reference r1
    i = 50;
    cout << "r1: " << r1 << endl;
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;

    /* a constant reference, constant object */ 
    const int j = 40;
    // int& r2 = j;          // Error, because j is a constant, it requires a constant reference
    const int& r2 = j;
    // j = 45;              // Error, because j is a constant
    //r2 = 20;                // Error, because r2 is a constant reference

    /* non constant reference, non constant object */
    int k = 30;
    int& r3 = k;
    r3 = 10;                              // update 
    cout << "r3: " << r3 << endl;
    cout << "k: " << k << endl;
    cout << line << endl;
    k = 40;                              // update
    cout << "r3: " << r3 << endl;
    cout << "k: " << k << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT again again: Now, I'm confused with "a reference must be initialized when it is defined, and cannot be modified later".

```
/* how to understand a reference can not be used to address a different variable */
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int& r = a;              // r is a reference, which references variable (object) a
    r = b;                   // expect an error, but did not get an error
    cout<< "a: " << a << endl; //2
    cout<< "b: " << a << endl; //2
    cout<< "r: " << a << endl; //2
```

Comment: Sorry if it is too naive. I thought pointer and reference are the same. So they are not?

Comment: not in C++.  Some other languages are using _reference_ for something closer to what is called _pointer_ in C++ than what is called _pointer_.

Comment: @kkxx in a way, they are. AFAIK, references are implemented through the means of pointers in C++ compilers.

Comment: At a lower-level const or non-const are the same thing just as pointers and references are the same thing. However, essential point is that the higher level abstractions govern how you can write correct code in this or that situation.

Comment: @kkxx, I've added another duplicate which should answer your clarified question.